# Purpose of the mine-full and theirs-full commands

Tags: svn

According to the docs:

> (mc) mine-conflict    - accept my
> version for all conflicts (same)
> (tc) theirs-conflict  - accept their
> version for all conflicts (same)
>
> (mf) mine-full        - accept my
> version of entire file (even
> non-conflicts)
> (tf) theirs-full - accept their version of entire file (same)

I don't understand the difference between the *-conflict and *-full commands.  It seems like it would get you the same results.

---

More:
See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121158/a-example-of-a-change-that-is-not-a-conflict) for a more detailed response to this question.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The 'conflicts' version will use the specified copy for the conflicts only, letting the normal merge work for any other changes.

Using the 'full' version will use the entire file as specified, disregarding the results of the merge.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

Comment: This is a great summary, see this thread for a more detail response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121158/a-example-of-a-change-that-is-not-a-conflict

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 33):

mine-conflict will use your code in every conflict situation, but still do regular merging in all other situations.

mine-full will use your entire file, throwing away all changes in theirs.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why the downvotes on this answer.  Is it technically incorrect? It's essentially the same information as the accepted answer, just doesn't contain the link to the redbook, and it's not a copy of his answer since it was actually given before his.