# When I want to modify a binary file on subversion, can I lock the file on all branches one time?

Tags: svn, locking, branch

We have a SVN repository. There are many branches on the repository. Most files in repository are text files, but there are some binray files (some .xls and .fla files) on each branch. These binary files cannot be automatically merged, so we set svn:needs-lock on these files.

The problem is, even when I have locked a file on one branch, other people still can modify that file on another branch. Finally when we merge changes between branches, these files conflict.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure why this received a "not constructive" vote ..)

Comment: Even if you could lock the file on all branches somehow, wouldn't you still run into the same problem if two people edited (using lock-modify-unlock) the same file in different branches at different times? Just trying to understand the problem you're facing here.

Comment: @GregHewgill You are right. I think I need a way to mark a file on a branch is 'immutable', until all changes from other branches are merged.

Answer (score 1):

The other approach would be to let the conflict happen and ignore them for those file:

- "[Purpose of the `mine-full` and `theirs-full` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113430/purpose-of-the-mine-full-and-theirs-full-commands)": `mine-full` could help keep your version
- "[Subversion - Always resolve conflicts using mine for a set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002135/subversion-always-resolve-conflicts-using-mine-for-a-set-of-files)": that is another approach, but which wouldn't work for the a merge without conflict.

Comment: This approach is good for generated files, but not for my case. Our binary files are some .xls files.